# dot(.)s are missing here & there in the mail html while sending PEAR Mail_Mime emails

Tags: php, email, pear, mime

I am sending a mail using PEAR's mail and mail_mime packages and sample code as below:

```
$sendStart=array();
require_once('Mail.php');
require_once('Mail/mime.php');

$sendStart['mail'] =& Mail::factory('mail');
$sendStart['mime'] = new Mail_mime("\n");

$sendStart['mime']->setHTMLBody($html);
$sendStart['headers']['Subject']=$title;
$sendStart['headers']['X-SMTPAPI']='{"category": ["MailID-XXX"]}';

$body=$sendStart['mime']->get(array(
        'html_charset'=>'UTF-8',
        'text_charset'=>'UTF-8',
        'head_charset'=>'UTF-8'
    ));

//echo ($sendStart['mime']->_htmlbody); exit;
$sendStart['mail']->send('xxx@example.com',$sendStart['mime']->headers($sendStart['headers']),$body);
```

I am facing a strange issue while sending the mails through this code. I have images inside the email body, sometimes the images not displaying. When I debug the issue, I found that `.` is missing in the image url. But if I print the mail just before the send line (as I comment out in the code) it prints with the image perfectly.

correct image url: `http://www.domain.com/image.png`

in the mail : `http://www.domaincom/image.png` or `http://www.domain.com/imagepng` ... etc.

part of the HTML code which has the image as below:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="image-table image-2" align="center" style="float:none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:left;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="element" style="text-align: left;height: auto;overflow: hidden;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]><img alt="Placeholder Image" src="http://www.domain.com/image.png" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block; clear: none; float: none;    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;display:none; mso-hide: none;" align="center" width="394"><![endif]--><![if !mso]><!-- --><img alt="Placeholder Image" src="http://www.domain.com/image.png" style="outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: block;clear: none;float: none;width: 100%;height: auto;max-width: 394px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;*width: 394px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" align="center"><!--<![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the very strange thing is it is displaying properly in outlook but not in other clients as for outlook I have separate code(as per the code).

Does anybody have any idea how to debug the issue or any comment on this issue.

**Edited:**

This issue is nothing to do with any specific tag (although I explain it using image tag), I experience it in several places such as in styles.

example : `line-heigth:1.5;` is the original and it changes to `line-heigth:15;` while sending out.

Basically it just remove the `.` here & there in the email HTML.

Comment: What are the values of `$html` and `$body`?

Comment: actually its little bit big html template which I can't put inside the question although I will edit it with relevant image part, @DaveChen please check the edited question

Comment: Interesting... you send different emails for MS-Outlook? How do you know in advance what receiver uses what email client?

Comment: @arkascha no, as in the code for outlook I used `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` , and for non outlook `<![if !mso]>` inside the template, so when it view in the client it takes the correct code

Comment: So the old thing is still required, even today, to create special solutions for each and every MS product? *sigh*

Comment: Do you have any way of logging the actual outbound messages that are sent? Anytime I see "outlook" and "mail message problems" in the same sentence I start smelling an Outlook issue with the way it will process HTML-formatted messages...

Comment: @DavidW yes, I have a  log and the html there is perfect, but when I receive it I have this issue. Actually it is not a client based problem, it happens in gmail as well as outlook. in question i mention only a sample code, so it was effected to gmail and other email clients not in outlook

Comment: What library you are using? is it handcrafted? If it is a library can you share the repository url else what are the contents of `Mail/mime.php` and 'Mail.php`?

Comment: check the header in the mail is it correct ?

Comment: Are you sending UTF-8? Is your email set as UTF-8?

Comment: (Considering  dot stuffing) I think the problem is Its not adding extra (.) but removing the (.) in this case. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @JanithChinthana I am also facing exactly the same issue. Can you please tell me how you fixed this issue. Please give me an example of how you fixed.

Comment: @JanithChinthana I have created an SO ticket (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353635/dot-missingon-domain-name-of-password-reset-email-link-send-by-sendgrid) with my issue.  Can you please look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is caused by dot-stuffing; as the dot is used as a special indicator in emails. You can read about this in [the rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.2) where it says (emphasis added):

> To allow all user composed text to be transmitted transparently, the following procedures are used:
>
> - Before sending a line of mail text, the SMTP client checks the first character of the line.  If it is a period, one additional period is inserted at the beginning of the line.
> - When a line of mail text is received by the SMTP server, it checks the line.  If the line is composed of a single period, it is treated as the end of mail indicator.  **If the first character is a period and there are other characters on the line, the first character is deleted.**

It seems the client you're using to compose these emails does *not* implement the first procedure, while the server it sends the mail to **does** implement it; leading to dots disappearing.

The fix would be to make your client implement the padding.

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same issue. Can you please tell me how to fix this issue programmatically. Please give me an example of how you fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHPMailer, it will make life a lot easier.

Comment: I can't change the email system due to some reasons. but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of it -

```
     // Set up the headers that will be included in the email.
    $recipient = 'someemail@gmail.com';
    $from = 'someemail1@gmail.com';

    $headers = array(
      'To'            => $recipient,
      'From'          => $from,
      'Return-Path'   => $from,
      'Reply-To'      => $replyto, //based on your need
      'Subject'       => $subject,
      'Errors-To'     => '<<a href="mailto:errors@example.com">errors@example.com</a>>',
      'MIME-Version'  => '1.0',
    );

    // Set up parameters for both the HTML and plain text mime parts.
    $textparams = array(
      'charset'       => 'utf-8',
      'content_type'  => 'text/plain',
      'encoding'      => 'quoted/printable',
    );
    $htmlparams = array(
      'charset'       => 'utf-8',
      'content_type'  => 'text/html',
      'encoding'      => 'quoted/printable',
    );

    // Create the email itself. The content is blank for now.
    $email = new Mail_mimePart('', array('content_type' => 'multipart/alternative'));

    // Add the text and HTML versions as parts within the main email.
    $textmime = $email->addSubPart($textbody, $textparams);
    $htmlmime = $email->addSubPart($htmlbody, $htmlparams);

    // Get back the body and headers from the MIME object. Merge the headers with
    // the ones we defined earlier.
    $final = $email->encode();
    $final['headers'] = array_merge($final['headers'], $headers);

    // Perform the actual send.
    $smtp_params = array();
    $smtp_params['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $smtp_params['port'] = '25';
    $smtp_params['persist'] = TRUE;

    $mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $smtp_params);
    $status = $mail->send($recipient, $final['headers'], $final['body']);
```