# Dot missing(on domain name) of password reset email link send by SendGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid mailer on Ruby and Rails framework. In password reset email template we are sending a password reset link which looks like the following format (https://subdomain.domainname.com/password_reset/token/?some_other_params). Most of the time  the password reset link is emailed to recipient in correct format but for some customer it is not sending the proper link. The issue we noticed is "the dot is missing between (subdomain and domainname) or (domainname and com) randomly and the resulting password reset link to customer looks like (https://subdomaindomainname.com/password_reset/token/?some_other_params) which is a wrong link. This issue is happening only on production and occur very random.

I verified our variable which have domain name in our source code and verified the code which is generating the url and also thoroughly tested this and  their is no issue on our source code. On google i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227537/dot-s-are-missing-here-there-in-the-mail-html-while-sending-pear-mail-mime-e) question. I did't understand how to programatically solve this on SendGrid  email client.

mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  sendgrid_category Rails.env
  default_url_options[:host] = APP_URL

end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => "subdomain.domainname.com",
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

APP_URL = "subdomain.domainname.com"
```

mailer_helper.rb

```
  def link_to_with_ga(*args)
    args[1] = append_ga args[1], 'html'
    link_to *args 
  end

  def append_ga(link, utm_content)
    link << "#{link.include?('?') ? '&' : '?' }#{@ga_tag}&utm_content=#{utm_content}"
  end
```

_reset_password_view.rb

```
  <%= link_to_with_ga(t("users.reset_password"), reset_password_url(:token => @token, :locale=>@user_locale,:protocol => ( Rails.env.eql?('development') ? 'http' : 'https' )),:id => 'reset_link') %>
```

Please help me in solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: How do you set the domain in the first place? Is it hardcoded in the mailer body or did you configure `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`?

Comment: Domain name is set at environment/production.rb file as APP_URL = "subdomain.domainname.com". I am using the APP_URL through out the application where ever required.

Comment: And how do you set the host in the email? Something like: `<%= link_to ... _url(host: APP_URL) %>`?

Comment: @spickermann Yes, In view i have something like you mentioned. But that actually calls the Mailer.rb to get the full URL with password reset token.

Comment: And how do you set the domain in the method in the mailer? How does that helper method look like?

Comment: Can you show what code generates that link or how it's forwarded to SendGrid?

Comment: @spickermann I have updated the source code of mailer and helper method in question. Please review and help me. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman I have updated the source code of mailer and helper method  which generate the link in question. Please review and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you [set your default `host` for ActionMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798917/how-do-i-configure-the-hostname-for-rails-actionmailer)? I don't see any host settings here.

Comment: @tadman default_url_options[:host] value was included on Mailer class. Please review mailer.rb on question. Is that is good enough or do i need to set that to production.rb, but using pry i see the host name is printing correctly in dev env.

Comment: That's certainly closer. ActionMailer can log the output of the mail contents, so it's worth checking that's rendered correctly.